# Tor access for reddit.com causes 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I always use Tor for reddit.com, amongst other websites, and occasionally would get a 503 Service Unavailable response. Hitting F5 or new circuit for this site usually clears this. Now 503 Service Unavailable solidly for the last few days.

On Windows 10 desktop with ExpressVPN. I have tried both Tor browser and Brave Browser private window with Tor with the same outcome. I have also tried disconnecting ExpressVPN. I've deleted Tor and downloaded it again. No luck. All other sites I've accessed load OK without the 503 message.
Does reddit now blocking Tor or do I have a browser configuration issue?

Answer (score 3):

One workaround is changing the URL from https://**www**.reddit.com/r/... to https://**old**.reddit.com/r/... As long as you don't mind using the older (and in my opinion, vastly superior) Reddit interface then this is one way to bypass the problematic pages.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried the old.reddit.com and it worked. I've signed in and managed to change old.reddit.com to reddit.com. This works as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Reddit issue which unfortunately cannot be fixed from the client side. It's possible that Reddit is blocking Tor users. The only thing you can try is to use new circuits until one works.

https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/40300